# Can't open Base64 encoded image sent from Android to my Intellij server

Tags: java, android, base64, retrofit2

I can't see my image once I've saved it.

**Image to Base64 method in my Android project**

```
public String image2String(ImageView im) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) im.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, baos);
        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

**Server side method in Intellij for writting in folder**

```
try {
            byte[] imageByteArray = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(img);
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Lau\\Desktop\\Folder\\test.jpg");
            stream.write(imageByteArray);
            stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
```

There is no exception thrown but I can't open the file in the folder.

[Window overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6OrS.png)

`image2String` returns the following value:

```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```

While the string that I receive on the server is like this:

```
"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/4gIoSUNDX1BST0ZJTEUAAQEAAAIYAAAAAAIQAABtbnRyUkdC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\n"
```

In the server `imageByteArray` has a lenght of 2994 bytes and the file on my folder is 2,92 KB (2.994 bytes).

Comment: What's the result of your debugging? E.g what does `image2String` return, is `img` the same as what was returned from the `image2String`, how many bytes does `imageByteArray`contain and how large is the jpg file on your disc?

Comment: @jps I'm sorry I just added all that new info into the main post.

Comment: @jps I can see that the string its different but i dont know why, I decoded it with `java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode` just to avoid that possible error

Comment: thanks for quickly updating the post. So you got indeed a valid base64 encoded jpg, the second string is Mime encoded (base64 with linebreaks after 76 characters), so the use of MimeDecoder seems correct. I can't test that code right now, but with all the details added, I hope someone can help. When you get rid of the `\n`, the string can be decoded without problems on base64decode.org and you get the original image back. And 2.9k is also correct.

Comment: you're welcome. See also my comment under the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: BETTER WAY**

**INSTEAD OF EDITING THE STRING IN THE SERVER WE SHOULD ENCODE IN ANDROID THIS WAY**

`Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.NO_WRAP);`

**AND GET IT IN THE SERVER THE USUAL WAY WITHOUT EDITING THE STRING**

`java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(yourByteArray);`

**PREVIOUS WAY:**

I just had to edit the String that i was getting in the server by removing the quotes surrounding it with `img.substring(1, img.length() - 1)` and the \n with `img.replace("\\n", "")`.

The result code in the server is like this:

```
String fixed = img.substring(1, img.length() - 1).replace("\\n", "");
byte[] imageByteArray = java.util.Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(fixed);
FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Lau\\Desktop\\Folder\\test.jpg");
stream.write(imageByteArray);
stream.close();
```

**Special thanks to @jps**

Comment: can you try without deleting the `\n`, only removing the quotes? The mimedecoder should handle the `\n`

Comment: Sadly If I dont delete them manually I get the same error

Comment: ok, thanks for checking. On the other hand, when you remove the linebreaks you don't need a mimedecode and can just use normal base64 decode.